# Potential of a falling charged particle on a charged ground

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, electrostatics, newtonian-gravity

I have a one dimensional problem. At $z=0$ a negative charged plate $Q$ is placed. 
A negative charged body q with start velocity $v_0$ and unknown mass $m$ is falling toward the ground. It stops and starts floating at the hight $z=+h$.  I want to determine the mass $m$ of q. My solution is

1. q feels the potential energy in the field of Q: $V_E=\frac{kQ}{h}q$
2. q feels the potential energy due to gravity $V_G=-mgh$
3. q feels kinetic energy $V_K=-\frac{1}{2}mv_0^2$

We get an energy balance if
$$\frac{kQ}{h}q = mgh + \frac{1}{2}mv_0^2$$
And with this equation I will find the mass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That charge potential would only work if your ground was a point charge. The formula for a plane charge's potential is actually
$$V_E=-2\pi\sigma k q |z|$$
assuming its potential is set to 0 at z=0. $\sigma$ is the charge per m2
The potential for a gravitational field is
$$V_G=mgz$$
Since z will be positive, our potential is
$$V=z(mg-2\pi\sigma k q)$$
In this system, the charge can only float if V(z)=0. If it's greater than that the charge will always accelerate downwards. Otherwise, it accelerates upwards.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to play with conservation of energy since you know the force pulling him down and the countering force created from the electric field(which is -∇V ) and you alsow know the sum of this two forces...